# how to make a functional timer countdown and sync with MongoDB database in React Native

Tags: mongodb, react-native, timer, synchronization, countdown

how to make a countdown timer like `Min : Sec` and most of all i don't know how to sync timer with database for not cheating users with playing memory stuff on application.
also i want a function execute after timer finished.
i have seen some people using `ComponentDidMount()` or other class components. i want to make it `functional and using hooks`.
i would really appreciate any of you code lovers answer me. **database syncing** is more important for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useInterval hook for having a timer [useInvterval code](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

It takes a condition and block of code and also duration.
It runs that block of code every e.g: 4 minutes.
So you can give it e.g: 4 minutes and a block of code that fetches data from the database. and it fetch data every 4 minutes.

```
const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(true);

useInterval(() => {
    // fetch data
}, shouldFetch ? 4000 : null);
```